# Getting error on converting ppt to PDF

Tags: powershell, pdf, powerpoint

Can some please guide me what is going wrong with the code? I need to convert a PowerPoint file to a PDF file.

Code:

```
#Convert Powerpoint formats to pdf
Param(
  [string]$inputPath,
  [string]$outputPath
)
Add-Type -AssemblyName Office
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint
$ppFormatPDF = 32

$ppQualityStandard = 0
$pp = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application
# TODO: Why this property does not work
#$pp.visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse

$ppt = $pp.Presentations.Open($inputPath)
$ppt.SaveAs($outputPath, $ppFormatPDF) # 32 is for PDF
$ppt.Close()
$pp.Quit()
$pp = $null 
[gc]::Collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Error:

```
Exception calling "SaveAs" with "2" argument(s): "Presentation.SaveAs :
PowerPoint can't save ^0 to ^1."
At D:\AllAquent\Rambo\Digo\war\WEB-INF\classes\resources\pptToPdf.ps1:17 char:12
+ $ppt.SaveAs <<<< ($outputPath, $opt) # 32 is for PDF
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

Comment: Your error message doesn't match your code. Is the value of `$opt` really 32? Does your PowerPoint version actually support saving as PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Used [this script](http://pshscripts.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/convert-pptxtopdfps1.html) a couple of months ago, removed my own modifications before posting here. Hope this might help you!

Note that this script is designed to convert all Powerpoint presentations in specified directory to PDFs.

```
Function Convert-PptxToPDF { 

[CmdletBinding()] 
Param( 
$File, 
$OutputFile 
) 

# add key assemblies 
Add-type -AssemblyName office -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
Add-Type -AssemblyName microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

# Open PowerPoint 
$ppt = new-object -com powerpoint.application 
$ppt.visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse 


# Open the $File presentation 
$pres = $ppt.Presentations.Open($file) 

# Now save it away as PDF 
$opt= [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType]::ppSaveAsPDF 
$pres.SaveAs($OutputFile,$opt) 

# and Tidy-up 
$pres.Close() 
$ppt.Quit() 
$ppt=$null 

}

#Where your PDF will be saved
$OutputFile = "C:\Temp\" 

# File-extension could be changed to .pptx if needed
Foreach ($File in $(ls $OutputFile -Filter "*.ppt")) { 
  # Build name of output file 
  $pathname = split-path $File 
  $filename = split-path $File -leaf  
  $rmfileext     = $filename.split(".")[0] 
  $OutputFile    = $pathname + $rmfileext + ".pdf" 

  # Convert _this_ file to PDF 
   Convert-PptxToPDF -file $File -OutputFile $OutputFile 
}
```

I take no credit for this script.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks.. I will try and let you know.

Comment: does not work for protected pptx... give `Presentation.SaveAs : Invalid request.  Presentation cannot be modified.`